Convert Java WebFlux to Spring MVC
I need to convert a project from Spring Reactive WebFlux to Spring MVC due to an internal needed.
Can someone help me to understand the best way to do that in a better solution using Spring MVC ?
    private Flux<CoreErrorResponse> myMethodName() {
        return webClient.get()
            .uri(buildListErrorsUrl().toUriString())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(CoreErrorResponse.class)
            .doOnError(e -> log.error("failed: {}", e.getMessage()))
            .onErrorResume(e -> Flux.empty())
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(readTimeOutTranslateList), Flux.empty());
    }

    public Mono<MyClassErrorResponse> findMonoMyError(final String token, final MyClassResponse myclass) {
        return Mono.just(finError(myclass));
    }

That would be the best suited solution ?

import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyService {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public MyService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    private List<CoreErrorResponse> myMethodName() {
        try {
            // Assuming `buildListErrorsUrl()` returns a URI string, so you may need to convert it to a URL.
            String url = buildListErrorsUrl().toUriString();
            return Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject(url, CoreErrorResponse[].class));
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            log.error("failed: {}", e.getMessage());
            return Collections.emptyList(); // Return an empty list in case of error
        }
    }
}



You could use Completable future to consider timeout. So your code would look like:
public List<CoreErrorResponse> myMethodName() {
    try {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return restTemplate.exchange(
                        buildListErrorsUrl().toUriString(),
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        null,
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CoreErrorResponse>>() {}
                ).getBody();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Request failed: {}", e.getMessage());
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            // ensure timeout 
        }).get(readTimeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Request failed or timed out: {}", e.getMessage());
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}


Thanks a lot @kerbermeister, of course it will be better to translate the .timeout method from webFlux which was previously implemented. I was looking for that funcionality on JDK 21 but I am not so familiar with the newer java version.

@EDG I don't get what problem you're trying to solve. As I understand, you want to move away from reactive stack to default imperative. What kind of functionality you want to get from jdk 21?

hey @kerbermeister actually that is a new demand to move away the reactive springboot to classic spring mvc due to lack of knowledge. It helped a lot your last post once I was able to convert the timed out functionality from WebFlux to MVC.
I belive thats all for now, I really appreciate your help !
